# SQL - Selecting from a multiples values field

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm using Teampass, here is a minimised example of the tables schema

Teampass_Roles_Title :

```
+----+----------------------+
| id | title                |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | Title 1              |
|  2 | Title 2              |
|  3 | Title 3              |
|  4 | Title 4              |
|  5 | Title 5              |
|  6 | Title 6              |
  ...
+----+----------------------+
```

and Teampass_Users

```
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| login      | fonction_id                                                |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| AAA        |                                                            |
| BBB        |                                                            |
| CCC        | 12;21;                                                     |
| DDD        | 3;4;5;6;7;8;9;14;15;                                       |
| EEE        | 3;7;                                                       |
| FFF        | 3;7;                                                       |
| GGG        | 3;4;5;6;7;8;9;14;15;21;                                    |
| HHH        | 3;4;5;6;7;8;9;14;15;21;                                    |
  ...
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

the numbers in `fonction_id` are the ids from the table `Teampass_Roles_Title`
Instead of using an intermediate table, they opted for this model, and I dont know if there is any way to have for example a liste of all users that access to `Title 6`

```
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| login      | fonction_id                                                |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| DDD        | 3;4;5;6;7;8;9;14;15;                                       |
| GGG        | 3;4;5;6;7;8;9;14;15;21;                                    |
| HHH        | 3;4;5;6;7;8;9;14;15;21;                                    |
  ...
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  Do not store multiple values in a string column!  Do not store numbers as strings!  Declare foreign key relationships!

Comment: I'm using Teampass, and this is the database provided with, I didn't create the database, now i juste need to retrieve the values in this form

Comment: `<snide>`Yet another 3rd party package that misuses the database.`</snide>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really bad data model.  Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really, really bad decisions.  You can do what you want using `find_in_set()` and `replace()`:

```
where find_in_set(6, replace(function_id, ';', ',')) > 0
```

Comment: you're genius, unfortunatly i can't upvote you with a new account, thank's a lot it works

Answer (score 1):

The database model is not great, to say the least. The query that can do what you need is:

```
select
  u.*
from Teampass_Roles_Title t
join Teampass_Users u on u.fonction_id like concat('', t.id, ';%')
                      or u.fonction_id like concat('%;', t.id, ';%')
where t.title = 'Title 6'
```

However, this won't be optimal in terms of resource usage. I don't see a way around it, unless you fix the database model.

Answer (score 1):

With the operator `LIKE`:

```
select * from Teampass_Users
where 
  concat(';', fonction_id, ';') 
  like 
  concat('%;', (select id from Teampass_Roles_Title where title = 'Title 6'), ';%')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ht5Fv6bBpjxtzcumbN3hdA/0).
Results:

```
| login | fonction_id             |
| ----- | ----------------------- |
| DDD   | 3;4;5;6;7;8;9;14;15;    |
| GGG   | 3;4;5;6;7;8;9;14;15;21; |
| HHH   | 3;4;5;6;7;8;9;14;15;21; |
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just modify the `LIKE` like this

```
where function_id like '%;%6%;%' or function_id like '6%;%'
```